# Searching controls by name in Windows Phone c# application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to search controls by name in Windows Phone application? I know it's possible in normal desktop application written in c#:

```
string s = "label2";
            Control[] controls = this.Controls.Find(s, false);
            if (controls.Length > 0)
            {
                Label found = controls[0] as Label;
                if (found != null) found.Text = "new label2 text";
            }
```

In Windows Phone application 'this.Controls' is unrecognized...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

```
var control = this.FindName(s);

if (control != null)
{
    // Whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible - but with Windows Phone your controls are located within a tree-like structure called the visual tree. In order to find a control, you have to navigate this tree. I wrote a utility class a while bcd called [Linq-to-VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/) that simplifies this process.

Comment: KooKiz gave me simple way to do what I need it but thank You for answer